# How can I create an upload-only SFTP Server on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp

I need to create an upload-only SFTP Server on Windows.
I have installed OpenSSH SFTP Server according to https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/3627/How-to-setup-SFTP-on-Windows-Server-2016.html, but I can't set the folder permissions in a way that would allow the user to list folders, but not read data.

It was very easy to do for FTPS using Filezilla Server - you can set the permissions in Filezilla:
[Filezilla Server folder permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTQYz.jpg)

From some other posts on ServerFault I saw that it's possible to blacklist requests, so I thought that blacklisting the "read" request could help. But I can't find the way to do this on Windows.
I've tried specifying the "-P read" parameter for the SSHD service:
[SSHD startup parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eML15.jpg)
but it didn't work as expected.

Is there  any way for me to create an upload-only SFTP using OpenSSH in Windows?
Or maybe there is another software that offers Filezilla-like permissions? Hopefully a free/cheap one :)

Comment: how's about chmod -r+w that allows you to write but not to read?

Comment: I guess you missed the "Windows" part :)